# Number data type column is not behaving as number

Tags: oracle

I have a table in oracle which has column recid which is of number Datar type. The table is partition table and it has partition index on it.

When I query the partition like

`select * from table partition (abc)`
I am able to see value for rec id =50. But when I query

`select * from table partition(abc) where rec id =50`,

It doesn’t give any record .
If I do type casting as

```
select * from table partition(abc) where cast (recid as number ) =50
```

I am getting records.
Please let me know what might be the issue .?
The issue exist only for one partition and rest of the partition working normal.

Comment: Consider adding your DDL script or something concrete for people to review.

Comment: Just to make sure: in the second code fragment you have `where rec id = 50` with a space between `rec` and `id`. Is that a typo? Otherwise that may be the answer to your question (but in that case the query should throw a syntax error).

Comment: To see exactly what is stored in `recid` in that partition, try this: `select dump(recid) from table partition(abc) where cast(recid as number) = 50`. This will show the data type (or a numeric code for it, which you can look up) and the exact bytes stored for `recid`. Try that and add what you find **to your original post** (not in a Comment).

Comment: As well as the DDL and other information to form [an MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please also include Oracle version and patchset you are using and execution plans for the queries.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not behaving as a number, then it's not stored as a number.

Run a DESCRIBE (DESC) on your table in either SQL Developer, SQLcl, or SQL*Plus. It will show how the REC_ID column is defined.

If it's stored as a VARCHAR2, you wil get an error on your WHERE CLAUSE predicate for REC_ID, if not every REC_ID could be treated as also a number:

ORA-01722: invalid number

Like so:

```
SQL> DESC employees
Name             Null?      Type           
EMPLOYEE_ID      NOT NULL   NUMBER(6)      
FIRST_NAME                  VARCHAR2(20)   
LAST_NAME        NOT NULL   VARCHAR2(25)   
EMAIL            NOT NULL   VARCHAR2(25)   
PHONE_NUMBER                VARCHAR2(20)   
HIRE_DATE        NOT NULL   DATE           
JOB_ID           NOT NULL   VARCHAR2(10)   
SALARY                      NUMBER(8,2)    
COMMISSION_PCT              NUMBER(2,2)    
MANAGER_ID                  NUMBER(6)      
DEPARTMENT_ID               NUMBER(4)      

SQL> 
SQL> SELECT * FROM employees WHERE first_name = 50;

Error starting at line : 4 in command -
SELECT * FROM employees WHERE first_name = 50
Error report -
ORA-01722: invalid number

SQL> select * from emps_copy_num where first_name = 50;
EMPLOYEE_ID   FIRST_NAME   LAST_NAME   EMAIL   PHONE_NUMBER   HIRE_DATE   JOB_ID    SALARY   COMMISSION_PCT   MANAGER_ID   DEPARTMENT_ID   
          100 50           King        SKING   515.123.4567   17-JUN-87   AD_PRES      24000                                            90
```

The first query fails - because not every value in that column can be simplicity cast as a number by the database.

The second query works, because I created a copy of the table where all of the first_name strings were values that COULD be cast as a number.

Comment: This explanation is not consistent with a fact in the OP's post. Namely, `cast(recid as number)` should fail on the same non-numeric values as the original query.

Comment: Yup, it should always work or always fail - but we need their DDL and data.

Comment: My point is, the OP says without the cast the query "does not give any records." That is not the same as "fails", as in "with a syntax error." It is possible that the OP is blowing smoke, but if he is not, then something else is going on.

Comment: he also said it was a NUMBER, and if it as a number, there'd not be a question

Comment: btw, if you could leave screenshots and formatted code samples as comments, i would have left my answer as a comment. if i can get the OP to include their table DDL, then all will be good

Comment: @mathguy and Jeff : Pooja is a name for a female  :)

Comment: thanks @KaushikNayak and no disrepect intended Pooja

Answer (score 0):

You probably have spaces in there somewhere, eg

```
SQL> create table t ( should_have_been_numeric   varchar2(30));

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> insert into t values ('50   ');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into t values ('   50   ');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into t values ('      50');

1 row created.

SQL>
SQL> select * from t where should_have_been_numeric = '50';

no rows selected

SQL> select * from t where cast(should_have_been_numeric as number) = 50;

SHOULD_HAVE_BEEN_NUMERIC
------------------------------
50
   50
      50

3 rows selected.
```

but as already mentioned, if you are treating strings as numbers, then there is problems ahead in terms of spurious errors, not to mention potential performance issues because the optimizer also doesn't know that these are really numbers.